# How to flag multiple photos in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, os-x

If I have multiple photos selected at the bottom row and press P, only the highlighted photo of the selection is flagged, not the whole selection.

In develop module, how do I flag multiple photos at the bottom?

Comment: Are you not on LR5? LR 5.6 on OS X 10.10 *does* flag all selected photos picked when you press `P`.

Comment: I'm using LR5.6 on 10.10 and it does not flag every photo when I press p

Answer (score 2):

You can always right click after selecting the photos and flagging them that way. I don't know of a shortcut unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

So on the bottom left you have several different viewing options (right above that bottom row where all your photos are flagged). There's one with the number 1 in a box, one with the number 2 in a box, and then one with 4 boxes next to each other (and then arrows and other symbols if you keep going to the right). Click the symbol with the four boxes. This should bring the photos you've selected into the library filter and show them all in the viewer (whereas usually you'd just see one photo there). Make sure you've selected in the bottom row all of the photos you want to delete and then with them there in the viewer you can hit "x" and it'll flag them all as rejected. Then you can right click on the photos and you'll see the option to "remove photos." This should do it for ya.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows:
Press in this order; `E` > `P` > `D` on the keyboard.

1. In the Library Module:

   [image]
2. I have two images selected:

   [image]
3. Hit the Letter`E`
4. [image]
5. Hit the Letter`P`
6. [image]
7. Hit the Letter`D`
8. [image]

Comment: Nope doesn't work. Only the 1 photo gets flagged, the others won't

Comment: It _does_ work, using Lightroom 5 in Windows. Since you have now edited the original question to include OS-X, that changes the question. This answer is for Windows.

Comment: Doesn't do the same thing any more in Windows.  The first E puts you in Loup mode, with only one photo selected.

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom has been developed with a particular workflow in mind: It starts in 'Library' mode, where you are to review, cull and rate your images. Next, you move to the Develop module, where you Develop individual images. After this, you then can move into other post-processing tasks, such as Web, Print, etc.

This means that the Library Module is designed for rating images, and allows you to select multiple images and 'pick' or flag them. Develop module is designed for single images, so it is no surprise that selecting multiple in the contact sheet sheet doesn't work.

Use the Library Module.

Comment: Except that Lightroom doesn't allow you to pick multiple photos.  In Library mode, select a few from the strip at the bottom.  Now hit 'p'.  Only the first one is picked.  If you select multiple photos in the grid and hit 'p' all the photos are picked.  It's like the two bits were designed by two different UX teams.

Comment: Perhaps, but the strip at the bottom is simply a visual reference, as well as a tool to choose the image you are focusing on. I doubt its meant to replace the entire Library Module

Answer (score 1):

Soultion,

In DEVELOP mode,
Highlight all photos you wish to flag in the filmstrip,

MAKE SURE AUTO-SYNC IS TICKED (at bottom of adjustment sliders)

Now when "X" or "P" is pressed, it will batch reject/pick.

Just remember to "untick" AUTO-SYNC when adjusting now, unless that is your goal!

@leftsfordays

Answer (score 0):

Develop mode - focus shifts to the main photo displayed, but the filmstrip still shows the selected photos. Solution? **Right click on the filmstrip at the bottom -> Pick flag**

The other option is of course, Library Mode (shortcut key G like it was said here) and then Develop mode again after flaggin (shortcut key D)